# OpenCL Sum reduction across different work-groups gives the wrong result

Tags: sum, opencl, reduce

So I'm currently trying to write a kernel in OpenCL with the goal of sum reducing each row of a matrix (g_idata) into an array (g_odata). Said matrix is represented by a float array with column_count * row_count length, and the resulting array has a length of row_count. As such I've implemented the following kernel:

```
#define T float
#define Operation(X, Y) ((X) + (Y))

__kernel void marrow_kernel( __global T *g_odata,__global T *g_idata, 
            const unsigned long column_count, const unsigned long row_count, __local volatile T* sdata) {

size_t tid = get_local_id(0);
size_t gid = get_global_id(0);

size_t row = gid / column_count;
size_t column = gid % column_count;


if(row < row_count && column < column_count)
{
    sdata[tid] = g_idata[gid];
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

if(row < row_count && column < column_count)
{
   size_t step = column_count / 2;
   size_t limit = column_count;

   while(step > 0)
   {
        if(column + step < limit) {
            if(tid + step < get_local_size(0))
            {
                sdata[tid] = Operation(sdata[tid], sdata[tid + step]);
            }
            else if (gid + step < column_count * row_count)
            {
                sdata[tid] = Operation(sdata[tid], g_idata[gid + step]);
            }
        }

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        step /= 2;
        limit /= 2;
   }
}


barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

if(row < row_count && column == 0)
{
    g_odata[row] = column_count % 2 == 0 ? sdata[tid] : sdata[tid] + g_idata[gid + (column_count - 1)];
}

}
```

Said kernel is currently being instantiated with a work-group of 128 work-units. I currently have no control over the size of the work-group.

Now here's the issue: If lets say I've a row that's shared between two different work-groups, it'll return the wrong result, since it'll fetch the value in the g_idata, since it's impossible to access the result of the next work-group local memory. After the first iteration, that's the wrong value, and it'll afect the final result of the operation.

Anyone can give me an hint on how to solve this problem?

Comment: "I currently have no control over the size of the work-group." Do you mean you allow the OpenCL implementation to choose the work-group size? This seems an odd choice. Controlling the work group size will make solving this problem a lot easier. Can you explain what constraint is forcing you to give up this control?

Comment: Technically it's a design decision carried from other components of the project, which is a university-backed framework to simplify the development of HPC systems using algorithmic skeletons. Currently the OpenCL executor is implemented so that all operations use the same work-group size, which has been selected as the best solution for performance across Intel, AMD or NVIDIA equipment (a previous Msc Thesis demonstrated that), for previously existing kernels. EDIT: But feel free to give your suggestion: I may be able to pitch it in to the Professor that's responsible.

Comment: In that case, I'd do one of the following: (1) always have exactly 1 work-group work on one row, regardless of how wide the row is. If it's wider than 128, then get each work-item to sum column 0, 128, 256, … in a loop, and then reduce at the end. If it's less than 128, you'll just have to pad it, and the last work items in the row don't read any columns. (2) If the number of columns is much larger than 128, you can try assigning more than one group to each row. They can each do the sum & reduction, then accumulate the results across each row in global memory using atomics.

Comment: ([Atomics aren't directly supported with floats, but there's a workaround](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2016-02-09/atomic-operations-for-floats-in-opencl-improved/)) (3) If the number of columns is often <= 64, you can also get each workgroup to work on `group_size/column_count` whole rows (rounding down) so that you don't waste so much on padding.

Comment: @pmdj I've been able to implement the option (2) (still need to do some unit tests for much larger lines though) mixed with the option (3). I'm currently having some difficulty with the atomic add  part, but thank you for the help!

Comment: @pmdj mind to make an answer with what you said so I can flag it as this question answer?